# Attempting to use 'pkg' to build 'nextjs' app results in dependency errors and/or 404 errors once built

Tags: next.js, zeit-pkg

I'm attempting to build an executable of a small NextJS example app based on the example [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls) using [zeit/pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg). Problem is the only feasible entry point (**server.js**) seems to give me a bunch of errors not currently listed in their issues related to webpack compilation.

If you'd like to reproduce just [follow the instructions here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls/setup) and then add pkg. Also - here's the error output below.

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors
>   10:48:35 AM These dependencies were not found:
>
> - @babel/runtime/helpers/extends in D:/snapshot/pkg-ssr/node_modules/next/dist/lib/app.js
> - webpack-hot-middleware/client?autoConnect=false&overlay=false&reload=true
>     in
>     D:/snapshot/pkg-ssr/node_modules/next/dist/client/webpack-hot-middleware-client.js
>
> To install them, you can run: npm install --save
>   @babel/runtime/helpers/extends
>   webpack-hot-middleware/client?autoConnect=false&overlay=false&reload=true
>   (node:15964) DeprecationWarning: Module.chunks: Use
>   Module.forEachChunk/mapChunks/getNumberOfChunks/isInChunk/addChunk/removeChunk
>   instead
>
> > Ready on http://localhost:3000 Client pings, but there's no entry for page: /about { Error: Cannot find module
> >     'D:_experiments\pkg-ssr.next\build-manifest.json'
> >         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:592:15)
> >         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1278:46)
> >         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:518:25)
> >         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:17)
> >         at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1157:31)
> >         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
> >         at _callee3$ (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:202:29)
> >         at tryCatch (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
> >         at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:296:22)
> >         at Generator.forEach.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
> >         at step (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:12:30)
> >         at _next (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:27:9)
> >         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } Client pings, but there's no entry for
> >     page: /about { Error: Cannot find module
> >     'D:_experiments\pkg-ssr.next\build-manifest.json'
> >         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:592:15)
> >         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1278:46)
> >         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:518:25)
> >         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:17)
> >         at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1157:31)
> >         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
> >         at _callee3$ (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:202:29)
> >         at tryCatch (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
> >         at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:296:22)
> >         at Generator.forEach.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
> >         at step (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:12:30)
> >         at _next (D:\snapshot\pkg-ssr\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:27:9)
> >         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

Comment: clean-urls-ssr has an entry point of server.js file which is [custom server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing)

Comment: you're right @yuyokk - I was using that but I kept getting an error so I assumed I was wrong. There's still some issues but i'll post a solution once i've figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I'm having [some issues](https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/509) to that are similar.

Comment: longer discussion here for those interested: https://spectrum.chat/?t=8d16e978-6fa6-4a8a-8f44-d50b191c92f2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, the issue was that I wasn't packaging a built app. I needed to do a few things:

- specify the `assets` and `scripts` in the `package.json` like below (note that **dist** was actually **server** in my case because I had a custom server and middleware)

  `"pkg": {
      "assets": [
        ".next/**/*"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        ".next/dist/**/*.js"
      ]
    },`
- build the app first using `next build`
- then ensure that whichever way I built the package, I used the `package.json`. For me the best command was their [default example](https://github.com/zeit/pkg#config): `pkg .`

See the following article from Mike Hsu in case you want a repo and instructions to compare to: https://medium.com/@evenchange4/deploy-a-commercial-next-js-application-with-pkg-and-docker-5c73d4af2ee